# Boundary of unit square is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I've read some of the answers to related questions to this, but this is an idea I've been grappling with for a while and still can't fully get my head around.

$\mathbb{S}^1$ is a smooth manifold, and so we can induce a natural smooth structure on the boundary of the unit square, $\partial I$ by some homeomorphism (specifically I am thinking of $\frac{|| \cdot ||_\infty}{|| \cdot ||_2}$).

But then intuitively, the unit square should not be a smoothly embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ - so where exactly does this procedure fail in providing a suitable smooth structure on $\partial I$, which makes it as such?

By definition we need to provide an injective immersion which is also a topological embedding. But isn't the topology induced by the homoemorphism from $\mathbb{S}^1$ precisely the same as the subspace topology induced from $\mathbb{R}^2$? So the inclusion map is a topological embedding. It is obviously injective - so I surmise the immersion criteria must fail, but I cannot see (rigorously) why this is so! Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map from $S^1$ to the boundary of the square fails to be differentiable at the four points $(\pi/4, 3\pi/4, 5\pi/4, 7\pi/4)$ that map to the corners of the square. You can check this: write down the $xy$-coordinates as a function of $\theta$, and try to take the derivative.

That doesn't mean that the square's not a smooth submanifold of $R^2$ -- only that this mapping isn't an immersion of the circle.

By "slowing down" as you approach each corner, you can in fact make a differentiable map from the circle onto the square --- one whose derivative is zero at the four points mentioned above --- and that's about as close to an immersion as you can get: a $c^\infty$ map that happens to have zeroes in its derivative here and there.

Comment: The first part of your answer is what my intuition says - obviously no neighbourhood of the point (0,1) in $\partial I$ is the smooth image of some open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. However, I think the failure in my understanding comes down to the technical issues behind this.

I've used the given map to induce a smooth structure from $\mathbb{S}^1$ on the square - but I don't then use it afterwards when considering the immersion. So what goes wrong?

Comment: An immersion is differentiable by definition. But your map is not even differentiable, so how can be an immersion?

Comment: You *can* (I believe) induce a smooth structure on $\partial I$ via radial projection. But when you do, the inclusion map from $\partial I$ to $R^2$ is no longer an immersion (as you can tell by computing the composite map from $S^1$ to $\partial I$ to $R^2$, which is not differentiable). Since the map from $S^1$ to $\partial I$ (with the induced smoothness structure!) *is* differentiable, if the map from $\partial I$ to $R^2$ were differentiable, then the composite would have to be as well. Not very satisfactory, I admit. But it does seem to be a proof.

Comment: Brilliant, that seems clear to me. I always have trouble thinking explicitly, but your comment is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!